# Enzyme/Jest test for useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component that looks like:

```js
const PersonalGreeting = (): ReactElement => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date())
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setDate(new Date())
    }, 60000)

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>{date}></div>
  )
}
```

I am getting into an error that states `Jest: "global" coverage threshold for functions (89%) not met: 88.73%` and when I look at the logs, it says specifically my `return ()` and `clearInterval(timer)` in `useEffect()` are not being tested. Here is a screenshot:
[image]

I honestly am pulling my hair out trying to figure out what they want me to test. Here is what I have tested:

```js
describe('PersonalGreeting', () => {
  const setTimeOfDay = jest.fn()
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const useToggleMock: any = (initialState: string) => [
    initialState,
    setTimeOfDay
  ]

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.spyOn(React, 'useState').mockImplementation(useToggleMock)
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllTimers()
  })

  it('renders component as expected', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <TestWrapper>
        <PersonalGreeting />
      </TestWrapper>
    )

    expect(wrapper.text().length > 0).toBe(true)
  })

  it('Checks time every minute', () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers()
    mount(
      <TestWrapper>
        <PersonalGreeting />
      </TestWrapper>
    )

    expect(setTimeOfDay).not.toBeCalled()

    // 1 minute
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(60000)
    expect(setTimeOfDay).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
})
```

Comment: Try enzyme unmount(). The cleanup function in useEffect will only be called when the component is unmounted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unmount your  component, this will fire the return function in your `useEffect()`

See [docs](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/unmount.html)

Something like this

```js
it('Should unmount component', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <TestWrapper>
      <PersonalGreeting />
    </TestWrapper>
  )

  wrapper.unmount();
  // continue with your expect here

})
```